# increase and decrease a alpha value in a for loop dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to dynamically increase and decrease the alpha value in a "for loop" like shown below

for example if the 'for loop' is for 5 times and the alpha i need to change is "x" then

```
loop 1 --> x = 0.3;
loop 2 --> x = 0.5;
loop 3 --> x = 1.0;
loop 4 --> x = 0.5;
loop 5 --> x = 0.3;
```

Comment: `Question 1:` Why in a for loop? That will just mean that when you run the loop, the next time the object renders it will have the same alpha it started with. `Question 2:` Do you mean you want to fade in at a constant rate until halfway through the loop and then fade out at the same rate for the remaining half?

Comment: What i am trying to do is in a gallery the images on the left side of the middle image should have the alpha value fade in at a constant rate and all the images on the right must fade out at the same rate...

Comment: Ohhh okay that makes more sense, your question is worded in a way that suggests you want to alter the alpha of a *single* object in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

This was a little trickier than I thought, but here's a function I've created:

```
function progEach(callback:Function, amount:int):void
{
    var rate:Number = 1 / amount;

    for(var i:int = 0; i<=amount; i++)
    {
        var val:Number = (i * rate) * 2;

        if(i > 1)
        {
            // Return decrementing value.
            callback(1 - Math.abs(1 - val));
            continue;
        }

        // Return incrementing value.
        callback(val);
    }
}
```

Usage:

Create a testing function (this is called by the above function I've made):

```
function test(i:Number):void
{
    trace(i.toFixed(2));
}
```

And then run `progEach()` (I couldn't think of a relevant name for it):

```
progEach(test, 6);
```

You should get this output:

```
0.00
0.40
0.80
0.80
0.40
0.00
```

Change `amount` to anything you like:

```
progEach(test, 11);
```

Gives:

```
0.00
0.18
0.36
0.55
0.73
0.91
0.91
0.73
0.55
0.36
0.18
0.00
```

To apply this to a collection of images like you mentioned in your comments, you could do something like this, assuming that you have all of these images in an array called `images` in my example:

```
var i:int = 0;

function alphaImages(a:Number):void
{
    images[i].alpha = a;

    i++;
}

progEach(alphaImages, images.length);
```

Comment: +1 for a well put answer. I notice it never goes to 1, though

Answer (score 0):

Why not use greensock's [Tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/)? Simply include it and use it like so

```
TweenLite.to(object, 1, {alpha:0.5}); // turn's the object.alpha to 0.5 in 1 second
```

If you want to have multiple animations, you can append a few:

```
var animationSet:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();
animationSet.append(new TweenLite(object, 1, {alpha:1}))
animationSet.append(new TweenLite(object, 1, {alpha:0}))
```

Comment: cannot hard code the alpha value as we will not know how many objects will be available.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot (or should not) do this with for loops. ActionScript is not multithreaded. The code will pause the rendering on the screen to execute your for loop until it ends, and then resume the rendering.**

What you want to do is some kind of tweening behavior with alphas, and the nicest way to do that is with [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), as ido suggested. Don't underestimate this library, it is extremely awesome and all kinds of tweening can be accomplished with it.

You can create a Sprite to group the objects on the left, and another Sprite to group the objects on the right.

```
var groupLeft:Sprite = new Sprite();
groupLeft.addChild(objectLeft1);
groupLeft.addChild(objectLeft2);
addChild(groupLeft);

var groupRight:Sprite = new Sprite();
groupRight.addChild(objectRight1);
groupRight.addChild(objectRight2);
addChild(groupRight);
```

Then tween the two groups, regardless of how many objects are in each group.

```
TweenLite.to(groupLeft,  1, {alpha:1}); // fade in, 1 second
TweenLite.to(groupRight, 1, {alpha:0}); // fade out, 1 second
```

And of course, remember to download TweenLite, import it to your project, and import it in your .as file.
If the solution above doesn't directly apply, there is other ways of using TweenLite.

It can do everything you need.